# Handling Implicit Conversions with Nullable Types in C# Maybe Monad Implementation

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on implementing a Maybe monad in C#, and I've encountered an issue when dealing with implicit conversions for nullable types. My current implementation is as follows:

```cs
public readonly partial struct Maybe<T>
{
    private readonly T _value;
    private readonly byte _hasValue;

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = 1;
    }

    public static Maybe<T> From(T value) =>
        value != null ? new Maybe<T>(value) : default;

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value) => 
        Maybe<T>.From(value);
}
```

The unit tests for implicit conversion without nullable types are passing successfully. However, when trying to handle nullable types and perform the implicit conversion, I encounter the following errors:

```cs
[Fact]
public void ImplicitConversionWithNullableValue_ShouldCreateMaybeWithSomething()
{
    // Arrange
    int? value = 42;
    // Error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'.
    Maybe<int> expectedMaybe = Maybe<int>.From(value);

    // Act
    // Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'MaybeMonad.Maybe<int>'.
    Maybe<int> maybe = value;

    // Assert
    // ...
}
```

I understand that I need to handle nullable types and convert them to their original non-nullable types. I'm aware of the System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis namespace and its attributes that might be helpful. Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue and allow implicit conversion for nullable types in my Maybe monad implementation? Thanks!

---

**Update:**
I got a working overload for the static method `From`, which converts a nullable U to a Maybe with a non nullable T.

```
public static Maybe<T> From<U>(
    [AllowNull] U nullableValue)
{
    if (nullableValue == null)
        return default;

    if (typeof(U) != typeof(T))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported conversion");

    return new Maybe<T>((T)(object)nullableValue);
}
```

Now I only need a implicit conversion, but this is not easy, since I can't just receive a second type parameter, like above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my implementation helps:

```
   public readonly partial struct Maybe<T> where T : struct
   {
       private readonly T _value;
       private readonly byte _hasValue;

       public Maybe(T value)
       {
           _value = value;
           _hasValue = 1;
       }

       public static Maybe<T> From(T? value) =>
           value != null ? new Maybe<T>(value.Value) : default;

       public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T? value) =>
           Maybe<T>.From(value);
   }
```

Comment: This would not solve the problem. See updated answer, I added a method overload for the From method to convert a nullable type to a Maybe with a non nullable type